# Нумерованный список ol нумерует список только до девяти

Tags: html, вёрстка

Помогите побороть этот баг с нумерованным списком:

[image]

Список нумеруется только до 9 а потом идет отсчет с нуля, это даже во всех браузерах. Код списка самый обычный ол и пошли ли и все. Кто знает, что это может быть.

Comment: Не хочешь ссылкой поделиться? Или кусочек кода показать? То, что он самый обычный не значит, что в нем всё хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно не помню, но вроде проблема с отступами у элементов списка. Попробуй увеличить их, старшие цифры должны появиться.

Comment: Большое спасибо, это правильно.